# Relation between norm of a vector and sublattice to which it belongs.

Tags: inequality, orthonormal, integer-lattices

Given four rational numbers $m, n, p$, and $q$, define the lattices $L_1 = \{ (m\cdot x, n\cdot x) : x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $L_2 = \{ (p\cdot y, q\cdot y) : y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. That is, the lattices corresponding to the integer multiples of the fixed vectors $(m, n)$ and $(p, q)$.

Define the a lattice $L = L_1 + L_2 = \{ (m\cdot x + p\cdot y, n\cdot x + q\cdot y) : x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \}\subset \mathbb{Q}^2$.

Then let $L^*$ be the projection of $L_2$ orthogonally to the rational span of $L_1$ and $\lambda := \lambda_1(L^*)$ to be the length of the shortest non-zero vector of $L^*$.

Does the following hold?
$$\forall u \in L, ||u|| < \lambda \Rightarrow u \in L_1$$

(Obs: this question is a simplification of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108714/any-vector-shorter-than-lambda-1-must-belong-to-a-sublattice).)

Comment: By "orthogonal projection of $L_1$ into $L_2$", do you mean orthogonal to $L_1$ or to $L_2$? Though in either case, the answer to your question is no, that does not follow in general. If you mean orthogonal to $L_2$ (the way I would normally interpret it), then it is actually the case that $\|u\| < \lambda \implies u\notin L_1$. For orthogonal to $L_1$, it depends on the values of  $m^2 + n^2$ and $p^2 + q^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "orthogonal" you mean a projection orthogonal to $L_2$, then unless $(m,n)$ and $(p,q)$ are parallel, $$\forall u \in L, ||u|| < \lambda \implies u \notin L_1$$

Let $\vec m = (m,n), \vec p = (p,q)$, and let $\theta$ be the angle between $L_1$ and $L_2$, so, $\vec m \cdot \vec p = \|\vec m\|\|\vec p\|\cos \theta$.

The length of the orthogonal projection of an element $t\,\vec m \in L_1$ onto $L_2$ will be $|\cos \theta|$ times the length of the original element. I.e.,
$$|t|\|\vec m\||\cos\theta|$$
As $\|\vec m\|$ and $\theta$ are constant, the only way to decrease this is to decrease $|t|$, and thus the length of the smallest non-zero vector in $L^*$ must be $\lambda = \|\vec m\||\cos\theta| < \|\vec m\|$.
But every vector in $L_1$ is an integral multiple of $\vec m$, and therefore has norm $\ge \|m\|$.

Therefore any vector $u$ (in $L$ or not) with $\|u\| < \lambda$ cannot be in $L_1$.

---

If instead you mean a projection orthogonal to $L_1$, then the norm of the projection of $t\,\vec m$ onto $L_2$ will be
$$|t|\|\vec m\|\sec \theta$$
and now $\lambda = \|\vec m\||\sec \theta|$

When $\|\vec p\| < \|\vec m\|$, clearly $u = \vec p$ is a counter-example to the claim. Possibly, there are some $(m,n)$ and $(p,q)$ for which the claim can hold, but it is certainly not true in general.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the sublattices. I meant to project $L_2$ into $L_1$.

Comment: But thank you very much for your answer. It was helpful anyway. I realized that if we take $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that the angle between them is very small, then the projections of vectors of $L_2$ will be close to the original vectors, so, $\lambda$ will be close the length of the shortest non-zero vector of $L_2$, which is $||(p, q)||$. With this, it is easy to construct a counter-example.